# Sudoku prime triples

Tags: recreational-mathematics, sudoku

By a sudoku prime triple I mean a tripe $(p,q,r)$ of three-digit (base ten) primes which together use each of the nonzero digits $1$ to $9$ once each. I'm wondering how many such triples there are.

Using digit sums mod $3$ one can show the primes in any such triple are equal mod $3.$ I found two triples: first $(241,853,967)$ all $1$ mod $3,$ next $(281,467,953)$ all $2$ mod $3.$ I feel there must be many more but don't have programming skill enough to look. Thanks for any program results or other information.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##bVFBboMwELzzilWkNjYQiqGNVBT3WKnXXhGqKHFSB7JGBiqlyt@pDSRpqszJDDO7s7v1of1SGPe93NdKt4Ddvj44a7GBWsu9aDZa7aNWEaSJAwaz2QzesO6M8oUvfXgXbaexgRxyrfMDqJPRhwhWHGpYAVrX4G6k@BbAxy6BQtEQfHiIwQOCd0vOI@rDuj3Ugo@KT6UqOjg3SoMEiaBz3ArCfIktQdcNgydqKnhsymchN2OjVGYX0qLksSs9dmRX7Kg9SdzSBrJIksgtM5P2Na8accNSuqRcRC6R94x6jzbGDYseFjRNrD/SyI99QmJ3JFDhj9CKDAVpGmYpSzIzzJHRzHEqU6kRLbk@BQvDkNLFzR@UOsPxtueDTf2tumm1oQMt6iovBJmHc38@N46Ch855v1Vy3vfuz/eJK/9x074rgWRLJA06lMo@d5dnSQ2Ac3i@tlkUHgfmmDHMNQuTve9/AQ) code produces 816 as an answer.

Comment: There are 136 distinct triplets, which I've pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/U4CRibZn)

Comment: Thanks, @DonThousand -- I'd upvote if it was made an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is purely computational. This [code](https://tio.run/##bVFBboMwELzzilWkNjYQiqGNVBT3WKnXXhGqKHFSB7JGBiqlyt@pDSRpqszJDDO7s7v1of1SGPe93NdKt4Ddvj44a7GBWsu9aDZa7aNWEaSJAwaz2QzesO6M8oUvfXgXbaexgRxyrfMDqJPRhwhWHGpYAVrX4G6k@BbAxy6BQtEQfHiIwQOCd0vOI@rDuj3Ugo@KT6UqOjg3SoMEiaBz3ArCfIktQdcNgydqKnhsymchN2OjVGYX0qLksSs9dmRX7Kg9SdzSBrJIksgtM5P2Na8accNSuqRcRC6R94x6jzbGDYseFjRNrD/SyI99QmJ3JFDhj9CKDAVpGmYpSzIzzJHRzHEqU6kRLbk@BQvDkNLFzR@UOsPxtueDTf2tumm1oQMt6iovBJmHc38@N46Ch855v1Vy3vfuz/eJK/9x074rgWRLJA06lMo@d5dnSQ2Ac3i@tlkUHgfmmDHMNQuTve9/AQ) produces 816 results (removing reorder duplicates gives us 136). The triplets are in the [following](https://pastebin.com/U4CRibZn) pastebin.